# Visualforce and Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have written one apex class now i need help to display the list of list on visualforce page kindly help  apex class as follow:

```
public class AnimalVaccinationDueDate {
    List<List<VaccinationRegister__c>> lstdisplay {get;set;}
    public AnimalVaccinationDueDate() {
        List<VaccinationRegister__c> Vcc = [
            SELECT Animal__c, Clinic__r.Name, Clinic__r.Email_Preference__c,
                 Due_Date__c, Id, Veterinary__c, Veterinary__r.RegistryReminderDisabled__c 
            FROM VaccinationRegister__c 
            WHERE Due_Date__c = NEXT_N_DAYS:30
        ];

        system.debug('++++++' +Vcc);
        List<VaccinationRegister__c> monthly_vacc = new List<VaccinationRegister__c>();
        List<VaccinationRegister__c> fornight_vacc = new List<VaccinationRegister__c>();

        for(VaccinationRegister__c vac : Vcc) {
            if(vac.Clinic__r.Email_Preference__c == 'Monthly') {
                monthly_vacc.add(vac);
            } else if(vac.Clinic__r.Email_Preference__c =='Fortnightly') {
                fornight_vacc.add(vac);
            }
        }

        Map<Id,List<VaccinationRegister__c>> Contact_list_monthly = 
            new Map<Id,List<VaccinationRegister__c>>();
        Map<Id,List<VaccinationRegister__c>> Clinic_list_monthly = 
            new Map<Id,List<VaccinationRegister__c>>();

        for(VaccinationRegister__c vac_monthly : monthly_vacc) {
            if(vac_monthly.Veterinary__c != null) {
                if(vac_monthly.Veterinary__r.RegistryReminderDisabled__c == false) {
                    if(
                        Contact_list_monthly.isEmpty() || 
                        Contact_list_monthly.containsKey(vac_monthly.Veterinary__c)
                    ) {
                        if(Contact_list_monthly.isEmpty()) {
                            List<VaccinationRegister__c> lst = 
                                 new List<VaccinationRegister__c>();
                            lst.add(vac_monthly);
                            Contact_list_monthly.put(vac_monthly.Veterinary__c, lst);   
                        } else {
                            List<VaccinationRegister__c> old_lst = Contact_list_monthly.get(
                                vac_monthly.Veterinary__c
                            );
                            old_lst.add(vac_monthly);
                            Contact_list_monthly.put(vac_monthly.Veterinary__c, old_lst);   

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            lstdisplay = Contact_list_monthly.values();
            system.debug('++++++' +lstdisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the visualforce page that you've tried to make so far? If you know how to iterate over a list using visualforce, iterating over a `List<List<SObject>>` isn't much different.

Answer (score 1):

Maps of Maps or Maps of Lists:

```
<apex:repeat value={!Map} var="parentKey">
    <apex:variable var="childMap" value={!Map[parentKey]}/>
    <apex:repeat value={!childMap} var = {!childKey}>
        {!parentKey}
        {!childKey}
        {!childMap[childKey]}
    </apex:repeat>
<apex:repeat>
```

Lists of Lists

```
<apex:repeat value={!Map} var="childList">
    <apex:repeat value={!childList} var = {!item}>
        {!item}
    </apex:repeat>
<apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Page is not displaying any thing i have tried this:

Comment: <apex:page Controller="AnimalVaccinationDueDate">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:repeat value="{!lstdisplay}" var="List">
     <apex:pageblocktable value="{!list}" var="item">
      {!item}
      
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:repeat> 
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>

Comment: But its not diplaying any list any help ?